# SQL: Joining two tables - Result table should list all IDs (even those which are not in the Joining Table)

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join

I have two tables.

The first table is called "Types" and looks like this:

```
TypeID  |  Name
1       |  Test1
2       |  Test2
3       |  Test3
4       |  Test4
```

The second table is called "TypeParam":

```
TypeID  |  ParamName  |  ParamValue
1       |  heading    |  0.349
1       |  motion     |  1
1       |  shape      |  F
1       |  slumber    |  0|0
3       |  motion     |  2
3       |  shape      |  B
4       |  shape      |  B
5       |  shape      |  F
```

What I am trying to achieve is to (left?) join both tables. The result should
list ALL Types with the associated shape. If there is no shape parameter listet in the TypeParam-table, the the value in the result table should be NULL. If there are
additional TypeID entries in the TypeParam-table which are not listed in the
Type-table, the result table should NOT include them.

The result table should look like this:

```
TypeID  |  Name    |  Shape
1       |  Test1   |  F
2       |  Test2   |  null
3       |  Test3   |  B
4       |  Test4   |  B
```

What I have tried so far is this SQL statement which already lists alle Types with
the associated shape. But Types, for which there are no shape entries in the TypeParam-table are not listed. How can I achieve this? I want the missing entry (TypeID = 2, shape = null) in the result table. The entry for TypeID = 5 in the TypeParam-table must not be listed in the result table as it is not listed in the Type table.

```
SELECT Type.TypeID AS TypeID, Type.Name AS Name, TypeParam.ParamValue AS Shape 
FROM Type LEFT JOIN TypeParam ON TypeParam.TypeID = Type.TypeID
WHERE TypeParam.ParamName = 'shape'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Replace `WHERE` with `AND`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid  I changed the WHERE to AND and tried to test it in MS Access but if I run the query a window pops up saying: JOIN expression not supported. Any ideas? With "WHERE" the query is running btw.

Comment: @user7335295 The fact that you have tagged the question with `MySQL` probably lead people to assume that you are using `MySQL` rather than `MS-Access`....  I don't think MS-Access allows constants in the join predicate, so you would need to use a subquery, something like:. `LEFT JOIN (SELECT TypeID, ParamValue  FROM TypeParam WHERE ParamName = 'shape') AS tp ON tp.TypeID = Type.TypeID`

Comment: @GarethD This did the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access, the simplest solution is probably a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT tp.ParamValue
        FROM TypeParam as tp
        WHERE tp.TypeID = t.TypeID AND tp.ParamName = "shape"
       ) as Shape 
FROM Type as t;
```

Note:  This will report an error if there are multiple "shapes" for a given `TypeId`.  If that is a possibility, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and explanation on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `TypeParam.ParamName = 'shape'` condition to `ON Cluase`

```
SELECT Type.TypeID AS TypeID, Type.Name AS Name, TypeParam.ParamValue AS Shape 
FROM Type LEFT JOIN TypeParam ON TypeParam.TypeID = Type.TypeID
and TypeParam.ParamName = 'shape'
```

Comment: I support Fahmi's answer.  Left Join semantics are lost when using WHERE clause in this example.  Using AND makes sure LJ semantics are in play.

Comment: @Fahmi I changed the WHERE to AND and tried to test it in MS Access but if I run it a window pops up saying: JOIN expression not supported. Any ideas? With "WHERE" the query is running

Answer (score 1):

As @GarethD pointed out in the comments, I am using MS-Access and therefore using a subquery solved the issue. Using `LEFT JOIN (SELECT TypeID, ParamValue  FROM TypeParam WHERE ParamName = 'shape') AS tp ON tp.TypeID = Type.TypeID` solved the question.
Thanks!